# EditText.toString() not containing all text in onTextChanged event

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` object in Android, and I want to remove all whitespaces from it (it's my initial problem)

I implemented it with a `TextWatcher` listener on the `EditText`, and checking if the resulting string contains any whitespace, and if so, removing them and replacing the text (triggering a new `TextChanged`, but since the string will no longer contains whitespace, it won't remove them).

My current problem is the following, under certain conditions, the text obtained with `s.toString()` is only the text before the cursor. In example, if the text in the `EditText` object is "This is so`|`me text" (with `|` the cursor), the resulting string will be "This is so".

The conditions are:

- Write some text
- Place the cursor inside the text
- Write at least 1 character

At any point in those points, if I type a whitespace, my code works, and the string obtained with the `s.toString()` is ok. Only *after* those steps the problem appears.

My code is the following:

```
public class WhitespaceRemoverListener implements TextWatcher {

    private int start = 0;
    private EditText editText;

    public WhitespaceRemoverListener(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.toString().contains(" ")) {
            int current_start = start;
            editText.setText(s.toString().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
            editText.setSelection(current_start);
        }
    }
}
```

An other interesting fact, is that the bug appears only on physical devices, and not on Android emulators...

Comment: Take careful when you modify the text inside the EditText in its TextWatcher, since this modification will call these TextWatcher again, resulting into a loop.

Comment: And I wonder if this is a result of competition...

Comment: That is why I put a check if the text contains a whitespace, the second time it will not contains the whitespace, and should not change the text again.
I tried not changing the text at all (removing the `setText`) but the result where the same... the `s.toString()` was still giving me only a part of the text